# pyqtgraph pyinstaller build exe file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller, pyqtgraph

I tried to make an *.exe file from my python application that uses pyqtgraph and the pyqt library using pyinstaller.
Pyinstaller makes a single *.exe file without errors, but when I try to start it, I get an error that pyqtgraph is not found.

How can I build a single *.exe file using pyinstaller?

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller does not support dynamic imports, which are used in the latest release of pyqtgraph (0.9.8). However, the latest development code on github (http://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph) does *not* use any dynamic imports, and may work better with pyinstaller.

Another option is to try py2exe, which does have support for dynamic imports.